# How can i select specific anchor tag using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

i have two types of anchor tag as you can see.

First :

```
<a>Link</a>
```

and Second :

```
<a href="http://facebook.com"></a>
<a href="http://twitter.com"></a>
```

i just want to select only this type tags `<a>Link</a>` using jquery.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the `:not` css selector:

```
$('a:not([href])')
```

Select all `a` tags without an attribute `href`

[jQuery docs here](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)

Comment: The question is asking how to select `a` elements **without** an href attribute

Comment: @Quentin: answer edited. Thank you for pointing out my misreading!

Answer (score 6):

```
$('a').filter(function(){
     return !$(this).attr('href');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/3Sczq/

Comment: this can be done more easily.  See my answer below :)  Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/3Sczq/1/